Flutter tried to send a request of type FormData.fromMap() to Laravel but it was not read by laravel
I have a problem with the API Client using the Dio libarary, where when I try to send a text-only field I will send it using Map or Object, but when I try to send a file I use FormData, but the problem is that when I use FormData my request is not read by Laravel.
    Future<dynamic> _processRequestBody(dynamic body) async {
        if (body == null) return null;

        if (body is! Map<String, dynamic>) return body;

        bool hasFiles = false;
        final formMap = <String, dynamic>{};

        Future<List<MultipartFile>> processMultipleFiles(List<PlatformFile> files) async {
          return Future.wait(files.map((file) => MultipartFile.fromFile(
            file.path!,
            filename: file.name,
          )));
        }

        Future<MultipartFile> processSingleFile(PlatformFile file) async {
          return MultipartFile.fromFile(
            file.path!,
            filename: file.name,
          );
        }

        for (var entry in body.entries) {
          final value = entry.value;

          try {
            if (value is List<PlatformFile>) {
              hasFiles = true;
              if (value.length == 1) {
                formMap[entry.key] = await processSingleFile(value.first);
              } else {
                formMap[entry.key] = await processMultipleFiles(value);
              }
            } else if (value is PlatformFile) {
              hasFiles = true;
              formMap[entry.key] = await processSingleFile(value);
            } else if (value != null) {
              formMap[entry.key] = value.toString();
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error processing field ${entry.key}: $e');
            rethrow;
          }
        }

        print(formMap);
        return hasFiles ? FormData.fromMap(formMap) : body;
    }

Handling PUT request
    Future<Response> put(
          String path, {
            dynamic body,
            Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
            Options? options,
            bool unusedAuth = false,
          }) async {
        try {
          final requestOptions = options ?? Options();
          requestOptions.extra = {
            ...requestOptions.extra ?? {},
            'unusedAuth': unusedAuth,
          };

          final processedBody = await _processRequestBody(body);

          if (processedBody is FormData) {
            requestOptions.headers = {
              ...requestOptions.headers ?? {},
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            };
          }

          final response = await _dio.put(
            path,
            data: processedBody,
            queryParameters: queryParameters,
            options: requestOptions,
          );
          return response;
        } on DioException catch (e) {
          throw _handleError(e);
        }
    }

Using API Client example
    Future<BaseResponse> updateProfile(UserProfileData formData) async {
          final response = await _apiClient.put(
            ApiPath.updateProfile,
            body: formData.toJson(),
          );
    }

In Laravel
    public function editProfileUser(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::info('All request data:', $request->all());
        \Log::info('Files:', $request->allFiles());
        \Log::info('Has file test:', [
            'hasFile' => $request->hasFile('your_file_field_name'),
            'files' => $request->files->all()
        ]);

        return $this->response(500, "Error", null);
    }

Results Log
    \[2024-11-03 00:01:04\] local.INFO: All request data:  
    \[2024-11-03 00:01:04\] local.INFO: Files:
    \[2024-11-03 00:01:04\] local.INFO: Has file test: {"hasFile":false,"files":\[\]}

Everything is empty when using FormData.fromMap.
But when my input contains all text then it can
Additional information:
Laravel version: 10.48.22
Flutter version: 3.24.0
Dio version: ^5.7.0
My return files are all in the form of List<PlatformFile>
You can see the full API Client code on my drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jhk1gLhCySvfCrRlgqNNc4NDdJu9uNzk/view?usp=drive_link

Give me suggestions on what's wrong; is it with Flutter or Laravel?
What should I fix?
Is there a special configuration in either Flutter or Laravel?


Did you try calling the Laravel API outside Flutter through something like Postman?

Also check what $request->getContent() returns.

It appears that this is a well-known issue not with Laravel but with PHP. The solution appears to be to send a POST instead of a PUT or PATCH with a _method: PUT in the form body. You can add this additional field in the body while processing or later while making the request.

Use post instead of put:

   final response = await _dio.post(
            path,
            data: processedBody,
            queryParameters: queryParameters,
            options: requestOptions,
          );


In _processRequestBody:

return hasFiles
      ? FormData.fromMap(formMap..['_method'] = 'PUT')
      : {
          ...body,
          "_method": "PUT",
        };

Note: the ..['method'] syntax is the casacade operator and is equivalent to:
formMap['method'] = 'PUT'
FormData.fromMap(formMap)

Suggestion: Refactor _processRequestBody
You can leverage collection-for and Dart 3's pattern matching to refactor _processRequestBody to a more concise version:
Future<dynamic> _processRequestBody(dynamic body) async {
  bool hasFiles = false;

  Future<List<MultipartFile>> processMultipleFiles(
      List<PlatformFile> files) async {
    hasFiles = true;
    return Future.wait(files.map((file) => MultipartFile.fromFile(
          file.path!,
          filename: file.name,
        )));
  }

  Future<MultipartFile> processSingleFile(PlatformFile file) async {
    hasFiles = true;
    return MultipartFile.fromFile(
      file.path!,
      filename: file.name,
    );
  }

  switch (body) {
    case null:
      return null;
    case Map<String, dynamic> map:
      try {
        final formMap = {
          for (var entry in map.entries)
            entry.key: switch (entry.value) {
              PlatformFile file => processSingleFile(file),
              [PlatformFile file] => processSingleFile(file),
              [...List<PlatformFile> files] => processMultipleFiles(files),
              final value => value?.toString(),
            },
          "_method": "PUT",
        };

        return hasFiles
            ? FormData.fromMap(formMap)
            : {
                ...map,
                "_method": "PUT",
              };
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error processing map: $e');
        rethrow;
      }

    default:
      return body;
  }
}

